# How should I count all deleted rows IN PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, count

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_filter WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_istilik WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_nem WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_rek WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_soyuqluq WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_vent WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$db->commit();

$count = $del->rowCount();
echo $count;
```

Although this PDO works correct, but I can not count all deleted rows. I think i should give different variables each prepared queries and then gather variables. What is your ideas?

Comment: $count += $del->rowCount() after each query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you're not using parameterised queries and are not reusing the query, you don't need to `prepare()` it. You can [`query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) it as is.
2. `rowCount()` only returns the count for the last query. Due to that and because you're overwriting `$del` over and over, of course you're only going to get the count of the last query. There's no magic you can perform, you just need to call `rowCount` after every query and tally the totals.
3. But instead of a `query` + `rowCount`, there's [`PDO::exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), which already does exactly what you want:

   > `PDO::exec()` executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the number of rows affected by the statement.

   ```
   $totals  = $db->exec('DELETE ...');
   $totals += $db->exec('DELETE ...');
   ...

   echo $totals;
   ```

Comment: should I use begintransaction()?

Comment: If you want to ensure integrity through a transaction, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Increment counter vairable after each query execution..Try like this

```
$count = 0;
$db->beginTransaction();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_filter WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$count += $del->rowCount();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_istilik WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$count += $del->rowCount();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_nem WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$count += $del->rowCount();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_rek WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$count += $del->rowCount();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_soyuqluq WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$del = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM hesabat_vent WHERE model_id NOT IN (SELECT res_id FROM result)');
$del->execute();
$count += $del->rowCount();
$db->commit();

echo $count;
```